# Python Regex: Find matches over slighlty similar texts and return a dictionary (or a list of dictionaries)

Tags: python, regex, backend

I'm trying to find the matches in several documents and return them as a dictionary (or a list of dictionaries). The documents are in two formats:

Some have two categories with one element each:

```
"Kategóriák:Faj1 (alfaj:12345.1)
Pseuda_kategóriák:Faj2 (alfaj:678910.11)"
```

And others have two categories and more elements within:

```
"kategóriák:Faj3 (alfaj:121314.15)Pseuda_kategóriák:Faj4 (alfaj:161718.19)Faj5 (alfaj:20212223.24)"
```

I'writeing to right an expression that will find all the 'faj', 'alfaj' elements. Here is the code I tried so far, but it doesn't work:

```
def find_elements(text):
    elements = {'nev':None,
                'alnev':None, 
                }
    p = re.compile(r'((Kategoriak)(:)(.*?)(w+\W))')
    m = re.search(m, text)
    elements['nev'] = m.group(2)
    elements['alnev'] = m.group(4)
  return elements
```

My regular expression does not find the results. Additionally, I did not get there yet, but after I find all the elements how do I deal with the fact that the documents with more than one element will return two values to the same key? How do I update my dictionary?

Comment: Have you used a site like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to make sure that your expression is actually matching?

Comment: Szia! I am a bit confused on the formatting. Is "Kategoriak:" a key in the dictionary or part of the string?

Comment: He :) 'Kategoriak' is part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the numbers that follow "faj" and "alfaj" and you want all values in the string to be returned then `re.findall` finds all elements in a string that match the regex expression of the first group.

```
import re

s1 = "Kategóriák:Faj1 (alfaj:12345.1) Pseuda_kategóriák:Faj2 (alfaj:678910.11)"
s2 = "kategóriák:Faj3 (alfaj:121314.15)Pseuda_kategóriák:Faj4 (alfaj:161718.19)Faj5 (alfaj:20212223.24)"

def find_elements(s):
    elements = {'nev':None,
                'alnev':None}
    elements['alnev'] =  re.findall("alfaj:([\d\.]+)",s)
    elements['nev'] = re.findall("Faj(\d)",s)
    return(elements)
```

The output is:

```
In [18]: [find_elements(s) for s in  [s1,s2]]
Out[18]:
[{'alnev': ['12345.1', '678910.11'], 'nev': ['1', '2']},
 {'alnev': ['121314.15', '161718.19', '20212223.24'], 'nev': ['3', '4', '5']}]
```

As an aside: A dictionary can hold anything, from a single value, to other dictionaries, lists, data frames - you name it. So you can assign a list to a key dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is, I have several texts, and the only constant is 'Kategóriák:' and 'Pseuda_kategóriák:'. So I'm not sure how can I write a generic regex to work across several texts that follow the format I mentioned in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan could you provide a string example that illustrates your comment?